# Communication between Raspberry pi and Android studio Application

Tags: android, wifi

I've created a mobile application using android studio to control some leds and sensors, so I'd want to connect my mobile application to my raspberry pi to send and receive data, is that possible? i.e. I want to write a code in the raspberry pi (ex:connect.py) and my mobile application that connects the two together.

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on stepping into **IoT**!

The best way to get this done is by connecting your mobile application to a database and the same database to your raspberry pi as well.
The raspberry pi will be listening to the changes made on the database and trigger the functions like sending an email or moving a robo arm accordingly. The database is only responsible to act as a bridge between the app and the microcontroller.
And how do you connect to the database you may ask? You use APIs for that on both the client sides.
The mobile app can be used to send instructions like switch on the motor or receive data logs from the MCU. Again, the database is where each is connected.

You can check out one of my video demos on this at https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6731591459058839552/

Happy coding! :)

Comment: Thank you , this was so helpful. :) Is there a tutorial or something that can help me build the database?

Comment: A database to switch on some leds? I can not disagree more. And the question was about communication. Not storage.

Comment: Hi Eman! For starters you can learn how to integrate the Realtime Database of Firebase to your app and raspberry pi. There are quite a few videos available on YouTube that could help you with it :)

Comment: blackapps I think you don't know what we're talking about here. Please check out the use case carefully about which we are talking here. Other than that after a while I'll suggest Eman to learn about pub sub whichh will be more efficient for the use case. But since he's a beginner, going the mentioned way is the best!